# Use Laravel php artisan command to export database table as CSV

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I'm writing a artisan command to export the table from my database as a csv file.
But when im running the command, the CLI shows me only the data from the database and don't create a CSV File.

Comment: Any errors? Are you sure that user that runs command has permissions to do this?

Comment: @skido no , no errors. and yes the user has the permission.

Comment: have you tried making an artisan command that just writes some random data? Or in other words, try testing all individual components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works fine in my laravel 5.4 project

```
public function handle()
{
    $filename = "logins.csv";

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fputcsv($handle, array('customer_id', 'count', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'));

    fputcsv($handle, array("row['customer_id']", "row['count']", "row['year']", "row['month']", "row['day']", "row['hour']"));

    fclose($handle);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    );
}
```

creates file **logins.csv** in the project root directory

```
customer_id,count,year,month,day,hour
row['customer_id'],row['count'],row['year'],row['month'],row['day'],row['hour']
```

btw what is purpose of $headers array ?

> CLI shows me only the data from the database

maybe you have dd() somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this library: https://github.com/box/spout.

Allows you to create CSV, XLSX, ODS files easily like this:

```
use Box\Spout\Writer\WriterFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX); // for XLSX files
//$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::CSV); // for CSV files
//$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::ODS); // for ODS files

$writer->openToFile($filePath); // write data to a file or to a PHP stream
//$writer->openToBrowser($fileName); // stream data directly to the browser

$writer->addRow($singleRow); // add a row at a time
$writer->addRows($multipleRows); // add multiple rows at a time

$writer->close();
```

You will just pass the rows as arrays and that's it.

You can find the documentation here: http://opensource.box.com/spout/